# select join two table then order by latest upload time(uplaod_time column) in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, join, select, sql-order-by

I got two table   users(table 01)、record_dcm_upload(table02)
i try to query counts and latest upload file time by everylogin account(users.username)
like

```
SELECT record_dcm_upload.user_id, users.username, record_dcm_upload.upload_time, COUNT( * )
FROM record_dcm_upload
JOIN users ON ( users.id = record_dcm_upload.user_id )
GROUP BY record_dcm_upload.user_id
```

[image]

but my query sql got some problem (actually the result of upload_time not the latest)
how should i adjust my query code (hope user_id and upload_time all sort By DESC)

Comment: Share us how your expected output should look like. And please post in textual form not as image because it's much easier for us to try and reproduce your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.username, MAX(t1.upload_time), COUNT(*)
FROM record_dcm_upload t1
JOIN users t2 ON ( t2.id = t1.user_id )
GROUP BY t2.id, t2.username
```